# How do I change a data-tags attribute with an onclick event?

Tags: javascript, onclick, custom-data-attribute

I want the data-tags attribute on the Storepoint map to be "hope-for-men" if the "Healing for Men" div is selected and "betrayal & beyond" if the "Healing for Women" div is selected. I've tried looking at posts with similar goals, but I don't know enough about conditional programming to figure it out.

```
<div class="spouse-men-box eight columns alpha center">
<div class="groupboxes" onclick="openGroup(event, 'spouse-men-content')">
<h3 class="mB25 white">Healing for Men</h3>
</div>
</div>
<div class="spouse-women-box eight columns omega center">
<div class="groupboxes" onclick="openGroup(event, 'spouse-women-content')">
<h3 class="mB25 white">Healing for Women</h3>
</div>
</div>
<div id="storepoint-container" data-tags="hope for men" data-map-id="158752ddce0df0"></div><script>(function(){var a=document.createElement("script");a.type="text/javascript";a.async=!0;a.src="https://cdn.storepoint.co/api/v1/js/158752ddce0df0.js";var b=document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];b.parentNode.insertBefore(a,b);}());</script>

<script>// <![CDATA[
function openGroup(evt, groupName) {
var i, groupcontent, groupboxes;

groupcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("groupcontent");
for (i = 0; i < groupcontent.length; i++) {
groupcontent[i].style.display = "none";
}

groupboxes = document.getElementsByClassName("groupboxes");
for (i = 0; i < groupboxes.length; i++) {
groupboxes[i].className = groupboxes[i].className.replace(" active", "");
}

document.getElementById(groupName).style.display = "block";
evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}
// ]]></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write a new value to the data-attribute:

`document.getElementById('storepoint-container').dataset.tags = 'some new value'`

You have to do it in your `openGroup` function (I've done it in the end, commented everything out that didn't work):

```js
function openGroup(evt, groupName) {
var i, groupcontent, groupboxes;

// not working:
// groupcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("groupcontent");
// for (i = 0; i < groupcontent.length; i++) {
//   groupcontent[i].style.display = "none";
// }

groupboxes = document.getElementsByClassName("groupboxes");
for (i = 0; i < groupboxes.length; i++) {
groupboxes[i].className = groupboxes[i].className.replace(" active", "");
}

//not working: document.getElementById(groupName).style.display = "block";
evt.currentTarget.className += " active";


// this is the relevant part:
var storepointContainer = document.getElementById('storepoint-container');
if (groupName === 'spouse-men-content') {
  storepointContainer.dataset.tags = 'hope-for-men';
} else {
  storepointContainer.dataset.tags = 'betrayal & beyond';
}
}
```

```html
<div class="spouse-men-box eight columns alpha center">
<div class="groupboxes" onclick="openGroup(event, 'spouse-men-content')">
<h3 class="mB25 white">Healing for Men</h3>
</div>
</div>
<div class="spouse-women-box eight columns omega center">
<div class="groupboxes" onclick="openGroup(event, 'spouse-women-content')">
<h3 class="mB25 white">Healing for Women</h3>
</div>
</div>
<div id="storepoint-container" data-tags="hope for men" data-map-id="158752ddce0df0"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

`document.getElementById('storepoint-container')
.setAttribute('data-tags', groupName === 'spouse-men-content' ? 'hope-for-men' : 'betrayal & beyond')`